# Inserting Images in Specific Album on Picasa in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, picasa

I am working with an iOS application in which i upload images on Picasa web albums from my iOS application.When i create album firstly i check whether any album with the same name exist or not so i fetch all the albums with their name and album id with the below code.

```
for (GDataEntryPhotoAlbum *albumEntry in feed)
        {
            NSString *title = [[albumEntry title] stringValue];
            NSString *title1 = [albumEntry GPhotoID];
            NSLog(@"File Title:  %@ | ID: %@",title,title1);
        }
```

i get all the album name and albumid .
now i check with the current album name  given by the user.

```
  if ([title isEqual:albumName]){
       //do not create new album
       // return the album id
     }
   else{
  //create new album
   }
```

Everything working fine ,but now the problem is how can i send the albumid to the uploading method  which is below mentioned:

```
  - (void)_startUpload:(UIImage *)image:(NSString *)filePath{

        NSLog(@"album feed is %@",albfeed);
       // user/11106615845/albumid/6029121 gphotoID:60291215413
      //GDataFeedPhotoAlbum *albumFeedOfPhotos = [self photoFeed];

        //https://photos.googleapis.com/data/upload/resumable/media/create-session/feed/api/user/114789383162963173862/albumid/6025392474120084449
       //https://photos.googleapis.com/data/entry/user/1082642086705/albumid/60254095886065
        NSURL *uploadURL1 = [[[albfeed uploadLink] URL] retain];

        NSString *photoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"red_bull" ofType:@"jpg"];
        NSString *photoName = [photoPath lastPathComponent];
        NSLog(@"uploadURL1  : %@",uploadURL1 );
        NSLog(@"photoPath : %@",photoPath);
        NSLog(@"photoName : %@",photoName);
          NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if (photoData) {
            GDataEntryPhoto *newEntry = [GDataEntryPhoto photoEntry];
            [newEntry setTitleWithString:photoName];
            [newEntry setPhotoDescriptionWithString:filePath];
            [newEntry setTimestamp:[GDataPhotoTimestamp timestampWithDate:[NSDate date]]];
            [newEntry setPhotoData:photoData];
            NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:filePath
                                                       defaultMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
            [newEntry setPhotoMIMEType:mimeType];
            [newEntry setUploadSlug:photoName];
            GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service = [self googlePhotosService];
            SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
            service.authToken = authTokens;
            [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];
            GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
            ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:newEntry
                                              forFeedURL:uploadURL1
                                                delegate:self


didFinishSelector:@selector(addPhotoTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
        [service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:nil];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"@@@ Image not loaded");
    }
i don't know how will i send the specific albumid so that i don't need to create a new album ,if that album is already found in my account.
```

How can i achieve that??

I don't want to create another album with the same name,,get the albumid and upload images on the previous album.
please help me out.
Thank you for your precious time.